# Why isn't my file reading the inputs correctly in this program?

Tags: c++, file-handling

So I'm trying to build a program for myself(for the time being) where basically I have the option of adding in books that I've completed, including the name of the author and the dates of completion, which is supposed to add the input into a file, and then I have another option that's supposed to just read off the entries onto the txt file line by line to display each entry. The only problem is that when I'm inputting each entry, I can't seem to get passed the input for "author", and when it's stored into the file it looks like this for example: (after inputting "for whom the bell tolls") for/twhom/t0-858993460-858993460. It also doesn't seem to retain the entries past the first(incomplete) entry.

Anybody have suggestions for how I could fix this? File handling is definitely something that I've had some of the most trouble with, so I'd really appreciate figuring out how to fix similar problems I might have in the future.

Sample of what the input file should look like:

Title:                Author:               Date:

book1             name1             01-01-2022

book2             name2             01-02-2022

book3             name3             01-03-2022

Here's the source:
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//Program will enter books into a file and display the amount of books read, and the completed books
int main() {
    fstream completedBooks;
    int booksRead,
        monthOfCompletion,
        dayOfCompletion,
        yearOfCompletion,
        option;
    string bookTitle,
           author,
           booksFinished;

    cout << "book tracker: \n" << "1.) add entry \n" << "2.) print list \n";
    cout << "Enter which option you would like to choose: \n";
    cin >> option;

    if (option == 1) {
        completedBooks.open("completedBooks.txt", ios::out);//writing into book list
        if (completedBooks.is_open()) {
            completedBooks << "Title:              Author:        Date:" << endl;
            completedBooks.close();
        }

        completedBooks.open("completedBooks.txt", ios::app);//appending input into book list
        if (completedBooks.is_open()) {//Gathering input for book
            cout << "Enter the name of the most recent book you've read: \n";
            cin >> bookTitle;
            //Gathering input for author
            cout << "Enter the name of the author of that book: \n";
            cin >> author;
            //Getting input for dates
            cout << "Enter the month you completed the book: \n";
            cin >> monthOfCompletion;
            cout << "Enter the day you completed the book: \n ";
            cin >> dayOfCompletion;
            cout << "Enter the year you completed the book: \n ";
            cin >> yearOfCompletion;
            //Storing input into file
            completedBooks << bookTitle << "/t" << author << "/t" 
                           << monthOfCompletion << dayOfCompletion << yearOfCompletion;
            completedBooks.close();
        }
    }

    if (option == 2) {
        completedBooks.open("completedBooks.txt", ios::in);
        if (completedBooks.is_open()) {//displaying text in book list
            string line;
            while (getline(completedBooks, line)) {
                cout << line << endl;
            }
            completedBooks.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample input file or input entered via `std::cin`.

Comment: I recommend using `switch` with menus rather than an `if-else-if` ladder.  IMHO, the `switch` statement is easier to read and kind of built for process selections.

Comment: Warning: `completedBooks.open("completedBooks.txt", ios::out);` writes over any pre-existing book list.

Comment: Warning: The code has no checks for IO errors when reading and writing the files or getting data from the user. This turns stupid little trivial mistakes that could have been caught and handled into bugs. If you can validate correctness, do it. You'll save yourself a lot of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush `cin` before reading the line.

If you use this, should do the trick:

```
if (completedBooks.is_open())
        { // Gathering input for book
            cout << "Enter the name of the most recent book you've read: \n";
            cin >> ws;
            getline(cin, bookTitle);

            // Gathering input for author
            cout << "Enter the name of the author of that book: \n";
            cin >> ws;
            getline(cin, author);

            // Getting input for dates
            cout << "Enter the month you completed the book: \n";
            cin >> monthOfCompletion;
            cout << "Enter the day you completed the book: \n";
            cin >> dayOfCompletion;
            cout << "Enter the year you completed the book: \n";
            cin >> yearOfCompletion;

            // Storing input into file
            completedBooks << bookTitle << "\t" << author << "\t"
                           << monthOfCompletion << "-" << dayOfCompletion << "-" << yearOfCompletion;
            completedBooks.close();
        }
```

Altough, to get the desired output you will have to format the line to write in the file. You can use `setw` to give a maximum width to the title and author.